# Acceder a un script desde otro

Tags: c#, unity3d

estoy en un proyecto de unity y tengo dos scripts, me gustaría crear una variable en el primero llamada "contador" y que el otro vaya sumando valores, es decir, como muestro en las imágenes, tengo unas funciones que suman uno al contador, y el otro quiero que lleve la cuenta en un public aparte como muestro [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
no se si me explico pero gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, las líneas de código de deben subir como texto y no como imagen, **debes [edit] tu pregunta** y es importante que leas [ask]. Además te invito a que te hagas el [tour] para que entiendas cual es el funcionamiento básico del sitio y ganes tu primer medalla, ánimo !

Comment: Eso me suena más a eventos. Uno de los scripts podría lanzar un evento (ej: actualización) y el otro recibe el evento y el valor.

Answer (score 0):

Las clases vienen al rescate!

Suponiendo que tengas una clase con una variable pasos paa registra el numero de pasos

```
class SoldierController extends MonoBehaviour
{

    public var pasos : float = 1;
}
```

y aparte una clase que cambie la animación cuando ya has dado muchos pasos, la forma de obtener los pasos que se calcularon en el otro controlado es creado una variable del tipo de la clase anterior.

```
class SoldierAnimations extends MonoBehaviour
{
    private var soldier : SoldierController;
    //soldier.pasos;
}
```

Como siempre para crear instancias te saldrá em campo de entrada vacío, así que deberás de arrastrar tu script SoldierController.js y todo funcionará de maravilla.

El código está en UnityScript, pero seguramente no deberás de tener problemas pasándolo a C#

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a ver como puedo aplicar esto, aunque es c# no js :S

Comment: Deberia de ser algo como `private SoldierController soldier;`.
Si te ayuda la respuesta te agradeceria un voto positivo.

Answer (score 0):

Seria dos clases que Hereden de MonoBehaviour

Ejemplo.

Script que detecta

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Detect : MonoBehaviour
{
  Counter counter; //Se crea una variable con la instancia de otra clase, o otro script

    void Start()
    {
        counter = GameObject.Find("ObjetoContador").GetComponent<Counter>(); //Se busca en el metodo Start o en el Awake, el objeto que lo contenga, en este caso colocamos de ejemplo "ObjetoContar", ese objeto debe tener el script.
        //Tambien se puede colocar publico y arrastrar en el inspector pero por cuestiones de buena practica lo escribo de esta manera
    }
  void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
  {
    if(collision.collider.compareTag("Paso3"))
    {
      ...
      counter.count++; //aca accedo a la otra clase y sumo 1, cada que entre en colision con un objecto que contenga el tap "Paso3"
    }
  }
}
```

Y este seria el otro script

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Counter : MonoBehaviour
{
 public int count; //Variable entera de la clase Counter, la cual incrementara cada que entre en colision la otra clase con el tag "Paso3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé si me he enterado muy bien de lo que quieres hacer, pero puedo recomendarte esto para lo que he entendido:

En el primer script, pon la variable contador en public: `public int contador;` (Te recomiendo que la primera letra de las variables sea en minúscula, he visto que tú has puesto `Contador`).

En el segundo script, pilla la referencia del primero. Puedes hacerlo así para que sea más fácil: `NombreDelScript cont;` Luego, en el editor de Unity, arrastra el objeto que tenga el primer script en el nuevo hueco que te habrá aparecido al poner la línea de código anterior. Por último, haciendo referencia `cont` podrás acceder a la variable:

```
public void Contar(){

   cont.contador; //Esto debería acceder a esa variable con el valor actualizado por el primer script.

}
```

Hace tiempo que no trabajo con Unity, espero que funcione y que te sirva de ayuda. Si tienes alguna pregunta, no dudes en responderme. Un saludo.